# Discord.io - Bot emoji reaction after sendMessage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bots, emoji, discord.io

Hi I want to react with emoji after sendMessage but I'm using discord.io not discord.js and I can't find tutorial for me.
I tried also watch some discord.js tutorials but when I put there for example `message.react(':heart:')` It crash when I type my command on discord.

This is my code yet:

````
case 'donate':
  var roledonate = '470654619748663326';
  var serverid = '470557119230246922';
  bot.addToRole({
    "serverID": serverid,
    "userID": userID,
    "roleID": roledonate
  }, function (err, response) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    bot.sendMessage({
      to: channelID,
      message: "```Thanks for donating. ```",
  });
});
break;
````

Comment: There are some discord for helping you with discord.js [here](https://discord.gg/bRCvFy9)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to write there for some help :)

Comment: And there are documentation on their [website](https://discord.js.org/#/) ;)

Comment: Oh sorry you're using `discord.io` not `discord.js`, for `discord.io` it's [that link](https://discord.gg/0MvHMfHcTKVVmIGP) for their discord.

Comment: maybe I try make discord.js bot It is maybe better and more tutorials for it :)

Comment: Yes and if you can't find what you search, don't forget to search into [Github](https://github.com/) some Discord Bot code, you can find what you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `addReaction()` function:

````js
bot.sendMessage({
  to: channelID,
  message: "```Thanks for donating. ```"
}, function (err, response) {
  if (err) console.error(err);

  bot.addReaction({
    channelID,
    messageID: response.id,
    reaction: ":heart:"
  });
});
````

**References:**

- [`client.addReaction({ });`](https://izy521.github.io/discord.io-docs/Discord.Client.html#addReaction)